# Python: I don't understand what's happening with this generator

Tags: python, generator, coroutine

I'm curious as to what's happening here. Can someone who knows generators and coroutines well explain this code.

```
def b():
    for i in range(5):
        yield i
        x = (yield)
        print(x)

def a():
    g = b()
    next(g)
    for i in range(4):
        g.send(5)
        print(next(g))

a()
```

output

```
None
1
None
2
None
3
None
4
```

but when I switch around lines 3 and 4: the lines `yield i` and `x = (yield)`, I get the following.

```
5
None
5
None
5
None
5
None
```

I suspect the problem might me from trying to use the yield statement to both receive and send values in the same function. Is this not possible in Python?

I have successfully written a couple of programs that use coroutines, so I am familiar with the way they work, but I am confused as to the way this snippet of code is behaving. Any insights into this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Edit: Thanks BrenBarn and unutbu for your answers. What's happening here makes more sense when you expand the problem out as such.

```
def b():
    for i in range(5):
        yield i
        x = yield None

def a():
    g = b()
    print('* got', g.send(None) )
    for i in range(4):
        print('+ got', g.send(5) )
        print('- got', g.send(None))

a()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't quite get what you're asking, but basically: when you use `send`, it causes the most-recently-reached yield expression in the generator to evaluate to the value you send.  Note also that `send` advances the generator to the next `yield`.  One thing that may be confusing you is that you are printing the value of `x` inside the generator, and you are printing the value of `next(g)` inside `b`, but the generator is also yielding values at `g.send(5)`, and you aren't printing those.

In your first case, your first `send` causes the `yield i` statement to evaluate to 5 inside `b`, but you don't use this value inside `b` (you don't assign `yield i` to anything), so it does nothing.  Also, when you do `send(5)`, the generator is yielding None (from the `x = (yield)` line), but you don't print it so you don't know this.  Then you advance the generator again with `next(g)`.  The most-recently-reached yield is the `x = yield`, but `next(g)` passes no value, so `x` gets set to None.

In the second case, the parity of the calls is reversed.  Now your first `send` does send to the `x = yield` line, so `x` gets set to 5.  This `send` also yields the loop value in `b`, but you ignore this value in `a` and don't print it.  You then print `next(g)`, which is None.  On each subsequent send, `b` prints the value of `x`, which is always 5 because that's what you always send, and then `a` prints the *next* yielded value, which is always None (because that's what `x = yield` yields).

I don't quite get what you mean by "using the yield statement to both receive and send values in the same function".  You can certainly do this, but you have to realize that: a) a value (None) is still sent even when you call `next(g)`; and b) a value is still yielded when you call `g.send(5)`.

Comment: Thanks, I was as you said confused because I wasn't printing the results of `g.send(5)`. I also forgot that `x = yield` was the same as `x = yield None`.

Answer (score 4):

Using `traceit` to step through the program line-by-line:

```
import sys
import linecache

class SetTrace(object):
    '''
    with SetTrace(monitor):
        ...
    '''
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    def __enter__(self):
        sys.settrace(self.func)
        return self
    def passit(self, frame, event, arg):
        return self.passit
    def __exit__(self, ext_type, exc_value, traceback):
        sys.settrace(self.passit)

def traceit(frame, event, arg):
    '''
    http://www.dalkescientific.com/writings/diary/archive/2005/04/20/tracing_python_code.html
    '''
    if event == "line":
        lineno = frame.f_lineno
        filename = frame.f_globals["__file__"]
        if (filename.endswith(".pyc") or
            filename.endswith(".pyo")):
            filename = filename[:-1]
        name = frame.f_globals["__name__"]
        line = linecache.getline(filename, lineno)
        print("%s  # %s:%s" % (line.rstrip(), name, lineno, ))
    return traceit       

def b():
    for i in range(5):
        yield i
        x = (yield)
        print(x)

def a():
    g = b()                    
    next(g)
    for i in range(4):
        g.send(5)
        print(next(g))

with SetTrace(traceit):
    a()
```

we obtain

```
g = b()  # __main__:44
next(g)  # __main__:45                 # runs b until you get to a yield
for i in range(5):  # __main__:38
    yield i  # __main__:39             # stop before the yield; resume a
    ^
for i in range(4):  # __main__:46
    g.send(5)  # __main__:47           # resume b; (yield i) expression evals to 5 then thrown away
    x = (yield)  # __main__:40         # stop before yield; resume a
         ^
    print(next(g))  # __main__:48      # next(g) called; resume b; print not called yet
    print(x)  # __main__:41            # next(g) causes (yield) to evaluate to None
None
for i in range(5):  # __main__:38
    yield i  # __main__:39             # yield 1; resume a; `print(next(g))` prints 1
1
for i in range(4):  # __main__:46
    g.send(5)  # __main__:47           # resume b; (yield i) expression evals to 5 then thrown away
```

The comments on the right-hand side (above) explain why Python prints `None` then `1`. If you get that far, I think it is clear why you get `None`, `2`, etc. -- it's the same story all over again with different values for `i`.

The other scenario, where `x = (yield)` and `yield i` are reverse can be analyzed similarly.