# Python next and send in same generator

Tags: python, generator, send, yield

This snippet of python I wrote is not behaving the way I expect, given my understanding of `yield`. Perhaps someone could enlighten me.

```
def printvar():
    yield 3
    data = yield
    print(data)
    data = yield
    print(data)

x = printvar()
print(next(x))
x.send(4)
x.send(5)
```

What I expect:

```
3
4
5
```

What I get:

```
3
5
```

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two issues.  One is that by advancing the generator three times, you only advance it *up to* the last yield, not to the code after that.  The other is that `send` puts its value in as the value of the yield statement where execution was *previously* suspended, not at the next one.  Here is a step-by-step explanation of what happens:

1. Your first call to `next` executes the first `yield 3`.
2. Your next call to `send(4)` causes `yield 3` to evaluate to 4, but you don't do anything with this in `printvar`, so the value is discarded.  `.send(4)` also advances the generator to the first `data = yield`, yielding None.
3. Your next call to `.send(5)` causes this *first* `data = yield` to set data to 5, and also advances the generator to the last yield, again yielding None.
4. That's it.  You don't advance the generator any further, so execution remains stopped at the last `yield`, never executing the last `print`.

The thing to remember when using `send` is that it sends the value to the place *that already yielded*, not to the place where it's going to yield next.  See [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13115135/python-i-dont-understand-whats-happening-with-this-generator) for more explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
def printvar():
    data = yield 3
    print(data)
    data = yield
    print(data)

x = printvar()
print(next(x))
x.send(4)
x.send(5)
```

In your orginal code the send(4) goes nowhere
because the yield statement is not collecting
anything.